# AngularJS Mathematical expression to ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am quite a novice in AngularJS development. I am working on a project in which I have a table with set of inputs. I have used ng-model to calculate one input based on other two.
For example, I have a student object with correct, incorrect and unattempted questions as keys. For many students, I am using `ng-repeat` as shown below. However, when I do `ng-model=some-expression`, it prints an error in the console saying the expression is non-assignable. But it works. I am confused as to is there any way to solve this.
Thanks

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in studentData">
    <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
    <div  ng-show="selectedSubj.indexOf('Physics') > -1">
        <td><input type="number" min="0"  ng-model="student.correctPhysics" required>
        <input type="number" min="0"  ng-model="student.incorrectPhysics" required>
        <input type="number" min="0"  ng-model="student.unattemptedPhysics=noOfQues-student.correctPhysics-student.incorrectPhysics"></td>
    </div>
</tr>
```

Controller code:

```
$scope.studentData = ['Akhilesh'];
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedStudents.length; i++){
  $scope.studentData.push({name: $scope.selectedStudents[i].name, batch: $scope.selectedStudents[i].batch, 
    correctPhysics: 0, incorrectPhysics: 0, unattemptedPhysics: 0,
    correctChemistry: 0, incorrectChemistry: 0, unattemptedChemistry: 0,
    correctMaths: 0, incorrectMaths: 0, unattemptedMaths: 0,
    correctBio: 0, incorrectBio: 0, unattemptedBio: 0, total: ''});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

angular don't enable you to write expression inside `ng-model`. hence you can do this inside `ng-init`

```
<input type="number" min="0" ng-init="student.unattemptedPhysics=noOfQues-student.correctPhysics-student.incorrectPhysics"  ng-model="student.unattemptedPhysics"></td>
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.studentData = [{"name":"Akhilesh","batch":"A1","correctPhysics":12,"incorectPhysics":3,"unatemptedPhysics":0,"crrectChemistry":0,"ncorrectChemistry":0,"unattemptedChemisry":0,"correctMaths":0,"incorrectMaths" : 0,"unattemptedMaths":0,"correctBio":0,"ncorrectBio":0,"unatemptedBio":0,"tota":45}]
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<table>
 <tr ng-repeat="student in studentData">
    <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
    <div  ng-show="selectedSubj.indexOf('Physics') > -1">
        <td><input type="number" min="0"  ng-model="student.correctPhysics" required ng-change="student.unattemptedPhysics=noOfQues-student.correctPhysics-student.incorrectPhysics">
        <input type="number" min="0"  ng-model="student.incorrectPhysics" required>
        <input ng-init="student.unattemptedPhysics=noOfQues-student.correctPhysics-student.incorrectPhysics" type="number"   ng-model="student.unattemptedPhysics"></td>
    </div>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I tried this and it doesn't seem to upgrade it in real time on the view?

Comment: post the `studentData` array

Comment: `[{"name":"Akhilesh","batch":"A1","correctPhysics":12,"incorrectPhysics":3,"unattemptedPhysics":0,"correctChemistry":0,"incorrectChemistry":0,"unattemptedChemistry":0,"correctMaths":0,"incorrectMaths":0,"unattemptedMaths":0,"correctBio":0,"incorrectBio":0,"unattemptedBio":0,"total":45}]`

Comment: when I use just `ng-model` it changes as and when I change the inputs. Hope you get what I am trying to say.

Comment: @Akhilesh Chobey check the demo

Comment: The `$scope.studentData` is initially like this: `[{"name":"Akhilesh","batch":"A1","correctPhysics":0,"incorr‌​ectPhysics":0,"unatt‌​emptedPhysics":0,"co‌​rrectChemistry":0,"i‌​ncorrectChemistry":0‌​,"unattemptedChemist‌​ry":0,"correctMaths"‌​:0,"incorrectMaths":‌​0,"unattemptedMaths"‌​:0,"correctBio":0,"i‌​ncorrectBio":0,"unat‌​temptedBio":0,"total‌​":0}]`. When I was using expression within `ng-model`, even though it gave error, the value of `student.unattempted` changed in the view whenever the other two changed. However it isnt the case now.